# Fast C++ sine and cosine alternatives for real-time signal processing

Tags: c++, optimization, signal-processing, trigonometry

I need to implement a real-time synchronous quadrature  detector. The detector receives a stream of input data (from PCI ADC) and returns the amplitude of the harmonics `w`. There is simpified C++ code:

```
double LowFreqFilter::process(double in)
{
   avg = avg * a + in * (1 - a);
   return avg;
}


class QuadroDetect
{
   double wt;
   const double wdt;

   LowFreqFilter lf1;
   LowFreqFilter lf2;

   QuadroDetect(const double w, const double dt) : wt(0), wdt(w * dt)
   {}

   inline double process(const double in)
   {
      double f1 = lf1.process(in * sin(wt));
      double f2 = lf2.process(in * cos(wt));
      double out = sqrt(f1 * f1 + f2 * f2);
      wt += wdt;
      return out;
   }
};
```

My problem is that `sin` and `cos` calculating takes too much time. I was advised to use a pre-calculated `sin` and `cos` table, but available ADC sampling frequencies is not multiple of `w`, so there is fragments stitching problem. Are there any fast alternatives for `sin` and `cos` calculations? I would be grateful for any advice on how to improve the performance of this code.

**UPD**
Unfortunately, I was wrong in the code, removing the filtering calls, the code has lost its meaning. Thanks Eric Postpischil.

Comment: What platform? Have you tried vectorized functions from MKL?

Comment: If the sampling-rate for the table is small enough, you can do simple linear interpolation for values in between values in the tables.

Comment: Depending on how much signal-to-noise tolerance you have, you can simply create a fairly large table and perform linear interpolation between the values.  No "fragment stitching" required, whatever you mean by that.  I know from first-hand experience that this technique works just fine for real-time audio resampling in a very well-known DJ application ;)

Comment: It should work on Linux and Windows, currently we works with Windows. Can you please clarify about MKL?

Comment: Note also that this class only processes a single sample.  This is not inherently helpful for vectorization techniques.  Ideally, you would split these operations so that multiple calculations can be done in parallel.

Comment: @paddy, the problem is that for further processing (low-pass filtering) we use a recursive filter that cannot be parallelized. But to make batch processing in this place will probably be useful, thanks.

Comment: For my comment, I of course meant if the sampling-rate is *high* enough. Not small enough. :)

Comment: @StasDavidow: Have you considered doing a Chebyshev transform? You can make speed/accuracy tradeoffs that way.

Comment: @user14717, honestly I don't quite understand how to use Chebyshev transform here, perhaps my knowledge is not enough. We are working on scientific research and we use synchronous detection to extract the desired signal from the noise. If it's not difficult for you, tell more about Chebyshev transform.

Comment: @StasDavidow: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_poly/chebyshev.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know a solution that can suit you. Recall the school formula of sine and cosine for the sum of angles:

```
sin(a + b) = sin(a) * cos(b) + cos(a) * sin(b)
cos(a + b) = cos(a) * cos(b) - sin(a) * sin(b)
```

Suppose that `wdt` is a small increment of the `wt`angle, then we get the recursive calculation formula for the `sin` and `cos` for next time:

```
sin(wt + wdt) = sin(wt) * cos(wdt) + cos(wt) * sin(wdt)
cos(wt + wdt) = cos(wt) * cos(wdt) - sin(wt) * sin(wdt)
```

We need to calculate the `sin(wdt)` and `cos(wdt)` values only once. For other computations we need only addition and multiplication operations. Recursion can be continued from any time moment, so we can replace the values with exactly calculated time by time to avoid indefinitely error accumulation.

There is final code:

```
class QuadroDetect
{
   const double sinwdt;
   const double coswdt;
   const double wdt;

   double sinwt = 0;
   double coswt = 1;
   double wt = 0;

   QuadroDetect(double w, double dt) :
      sinwdt(sin(w * dt)),
      coswdt(cos(w * dt)),
      wdt(w * dt)
   {}

   inline double process(const double in)
   {
      double f1 = in * sinwt;
      double f2 = in * coswt;
      double out = sqrt(f1 * f1 + f2 * f2);

      double tmp = sinwt;
      sinwt = sinwt * coswdt + coswt * sinwdt;
      coswt = coswt * coswdt - tmp * sinwdt;

      // Recalculate sinwt and coswt to avoid indefinitely error accumulation
      if (wt > 2 * M_PI)
      {
         wt -= 2 * M_PI;
         sinwt = sin(wt);
         coswt = cos(wt);
      }

      wt += wdt;
      return out;
   }
};
```

Please note that such recursive calculations provides less accurate results than `sin(wt)` `cos(wt)`, but I used it and it worked well.

Comment: Depending on the task, you may need to recalculate sin and cos once in a while so the errors don't accumulate indefinitely.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze. Yes, recursion can be continue  from any moment, we can replace the values with exactly calculated time by time. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The recalculation doesn't  work the right way. 'wt' can only be set to 0 when ist exactly '2*M_PI'. So 'wt -= 2*M_PI is much more appropriate. And it should be set before 'sinwt' and 'coswt' are recalculeted.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use std::complex the implementation becomes much simpler. Technical its the same solution as from @Dmytro Dadyka as complex numbers are working this way. If the optimiser works well it should be run the same time.

```
class QuadroDetect
{
public:
    std::complex<double> wt;
    std::complex <double> wdt;

    LowFreqFilter lf1;
    LowFreqFilter lf2;

    QuadroDetect(const double w, const double dt)
    :   wt(1.0, 0.0)
    ,   wdt(std::polar(1.0, w * dt))
    {
    }

    inline double process(const double in)
    {
        auto f = in * wt;
        f.imag(lf1.process(f.imag()));
        f.real(lf2.process(f.real()));
        wt *= wdt;
        return std::abs(f);
    }
};
```

Comment: I also like to use complex numbers for such calculations.